# IndexOutOfRangeException when calling SqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollection<T>() but not in the Command & Watch Windows

Tags: c#, sqlclient, subsonic2.2, system.data

I have a very strage problem with the `SqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollection<T>()` method and I am not sure whether this is related to SubSonic, my database or .NET.

When the following line gets executed:

```
FlowerCollection myCollection = sqlQuery.ExecuteAsCollection<FlowerCollection>();
```

my application crashes with the `IndexOutOfRangeException` that occured in `System.Data.dll` and the `Additional Information` containing the name of a column in the `Flower` table (which does exist both in the database itself and in the generated SubSonic class). However when I execute the same line in the `Command Widnow` or in the `Watch` window I get the result I expect without any errors.

I tried to load the debug symbols for .NET but in this case there seem to be no source code available so I am not able to debug it like that.

Have you got any ideas what else I can try to find the bug?

EDIT: I just added a try/catch around this code block and it throws exeptions for each column in the Flower table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround...

my original `SqlQuery` was constructed with an argument limiting the columns in the result:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = new Select(new String[] { Flower.Columns.Name }).From(Tables.Flower)
```

after I removed the argument from the `Select` constructor it runs without throwing any exception:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = new Select().From(Tables.Flower)
```

Why it worked in the `Command` & `Watch` in spite of this remains a mistery...